# How do I get display resolution on modern macOS?

Tags: macos, display

Now that xdpyinfo is gone and Settings -> Display have no useful information.

How do I get the display resolution details?

UPD20220911 system_profiler appears to be broken in 12.5.1

Graphics/Displays:

```
Apple M1:

  Chipset Model: Apple M1
  Type: GPU
  Bus: Built-In
  Total Number of Cores: 7
  Vendor: Apple (0x106b)
  Metal Family: Supported, Metal GPUFamily Apple 7
  Displays:
    DELL U4320Q:
      Resolution: 4608 x 2592
      UI Looks like: 2304 x 1296 @ 60.00Hz
      Main Display: Yes
      Mirror: Off
      Online: Yes
      Rotation: Supported
      Television: Yes
```

While About This Mac -> Displays shows 42.5-inch (3840 × 2160)
I have resolution set to "Scaled" and text size set to the middle of the 5 options.

Comment: Did you try the system report accessible via „About my Mac“? Or do you need it in Terminal?

Comment: the above worked fine for me, but if you want to do this at the command line try `system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep Resolution` ?

Comment: Or: System Preferences > Displays > Display. Then click the "Scaled" radio button and it will display the current resolution and allow you to change it. If you don't want to change it just click back to "Default for display"

Comment: While we're at it, I believe you can open the "About my Mac" and click on the display "tab" that is second from the left. The resolution is shown there.

Comment: @jaydel You should give this information as an answer.

Comment: yes, system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep Resolution works as well as about my mac

Comment: Then click the "Scaled" -> perverse, but works also. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an answer. Warning: in addition to my solution, I've captured other solutions from the comments above.

I used this from the commandline:

`system_profiler SPDisplaysDataType | grep Resolution`

The other answers worth trying are:

- Find it via the "About This Mac" in the system report (@nohillside's answer)
- System Preferences > Displays > Display. Then click the "Scaled" radio button and it will display the current resolution and allow you to change it. If you don't want to change it just click back to "Default for display" (Steve Chambers' answer)
- open the "About my Mac" and click on the display "tab" that is second from the left. The resolution is shown there (me)

All of these work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Install [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer) from Github or via Homebrew (`brew install displayplacer`).

`displayplacer list` will show the current settings and all other configurations which are supported. You can then use the same tool to change resolution, orientation and color depth.